# Sorting in tarantool with min() if several records have equal secondary index

Tags: tarantool

```lua
  local orders = box.schema.space.create('orders')
  box.schema.sequence.create('orderId')
  orders:create_index('id', {sequence='orderId'})
  orders:create_index('price', {unique=false, parts={2, 'integer'}})

  local bestOrder = orders.index.price:min()
```

I'm searching best order (minimal price) with `min()` function over secondary index. How is Tarantool sorting records if they have the same price (secondary index)? I tested and look like by primary index. Is this behaviour standardized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tarantool has several types of indexes [1]. And some of are sorted some of are not sorted. For instance, the tree index [2] will be sorted, that means you can get bounds, and the hash index [3] is not sorted, means you can get bounds without copy and sort.

In your case, you use a tree index. So you can use min, max, bound selects etc for 'price' index.

**UPDATE (after had some talks via email)**

Tarantool returns *first* tuple by primary key for `min()` if several records have equal secondary index and *last* for `max()`.

This behavior is normal for Tarantool, and you can count that it would not be changed in the near future.

---

[1] https://tarantool.org/en/doc/2.0/book/box/box_index.html?highlight=index#module-box.index

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree

[3] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: Default index type is tree by this docs https://tarantool.org/en/doc/2.0/book/box/box_space.html#box-space-create-index
And `min()` plays well.

Comment: Thanks, mistyped. Fixed. it is so

Comment: But I don't know how tarantool sorts tuples with equal second indexes (price is 1 for several records). By primary index?

Comment: In your case, tarantool uses the secondary index ('price'), which is b-tree.

But if you try to select SPACE:select({}), then sorted order will be by primary key.